# Mapping of values does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create Web API following this [book](http://www.apress.com/9781484201107?gtmf=c). I got to the end of chapter 5 and when I send a POST request that should be working at that time I get HTTP 500 error. I am sending the following request:

```
POST http://localhost:1424/api/v1/tasks HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: text/json
Host: localhost:1424
Content-Length: 38
{"Subject": "Fix something important"}
```

I tried to debug an set the breakpoint at the beginning of TasksController AddTask method:

```
public IHttpActionResult AddTask(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, NewTask newTask)
        {
            var task = _addTaskMaintenanceProcessor.AddTask(newTask);
            var result = new TaskCreatedActionResult(requestMessage, task);
            return result;
        }
```

At this point everything seems fine as newTask.Subject = 'Fix something important'. Then it goes into AddTaskMaintenanceProcessor.AddTask:

```
public Task AddTask(NewTask newTask)
        {
            var taskEntity = _autoMapper.Map<Data.Entities.Task>(newTask);
            _queryProcessor.AddTask(taskEntity);
            var task = _autoMapper.Map<Task>(taskEntity);
            // TODO: Implement link service
            task.AddLink(new Link
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get.Method,
                Href = "http://localhost:1424/api/v1/tasks/" + task.TaskId,
                Rel = Constants.CommonLinkRelValues.Self
            });
            return task;
        }
```

Here newTask is stll ok. Then it goes into this:

```
public class AutoMapperAdapter : IAutoMapper
    {
        public T Map<T>(object objectToMap)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<T>(objectToMap);
        }
    }
```

But when I step into the next action I get:

> Mapper.cs not found
>
> MapperEngince.cs not found
>    and so on.

When it steps ot of those messages it return null to taskEntity in AddTaskMaintenanceProcessor.AddTask. The it goes into

```
public void AddTask(Task task)
        {
            task.CreatedDate = _dateTime.UtcNow;
            task.Status = _session.QueryOver<Status>().Where(
            x => x.Name == "Not Started").SingleOrDefault();
          /*  task.CreatedBy = _session.QueryOver<User>().Where(
            x => x.Username == _userSession.Username).SingleOrDefault();*/
            task.CreatedBy = _session.Get<User>(1L); // HACK: All tasks created by user 1 for now
            if (task.Users != null && task.Users.Any())
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < task.Users.Count; ++i)
                {
                    var user = task.Users[i];
                    var persistedUser = _session.Get<User>(user.UserId);
                    if (persistedUser == null)
                    {
                        throw new ChildObjectNotFoundException("User not found");
                    }
                    task.Users[i] = persistedUser;
                }
            }
            _session.SaveOrUpdate(task);
        }
```

Where it fails at _session.SaveOrUpdate(task); with message

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert:
>   [WebApi2Book.Data.Entities.Task][SQL: INSERT INTO [Task] (Subject,
>   StartDate, DueDate, CompletedDate, CreatedDate, StatusId,
>   CreatedUserId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StatusId', table 'WebApi2BookDb.dbo.Task'; column does
>   not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

My guess is that there is something missing in automapper setup and that is the reason for all the values being null, but I have just started working with this so I don't know.

The project can be downloaded from [here](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1577/) and it is chapter 5. In original source I don't get messages that something is missing but